# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when comparing the arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, express

I have a array having JSON values

```
category = [ {"categoryName":"abcd","productName":"chicken biriyani","price":100,"quantity":"medium"}, {"categoryName":"biriyani","productName":"mutton biriyani","price":130,"quantity":"medium"} ]
```

I have to check for the required parameters for the above category array.
so I created a required parameters array.
var reqarray = ['categoryName','productName','price','quantity'];

I created the sample code for checking the values of reqarray and each value of category.But it is not working

```
var categoryList = [ {"categoryName":"abcd","productName":"chicken biriyani","price":100,"quantity":"medium"}, {"categoryName":"biriyani","productName":"mutton biriyani","price":130,"quantity":"medium"} ];
for(var i in categoryList){

        var reqarray =['categoryName','productName','price','quantity'];
        for(var j in arr){
            if(categoryList[i].reqarray[j]=='null' || categoryList[i].reqarray[j] == " "){
                console.log("data is null");
            }
            else if(categoryList[i].reqarray[j] == undefined){
                console.log("required parameters");
            }
            else{
                console.log("ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code shows an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: What is `arr`? And I guess `categoryList[i].reqarray[j]` should be `categoryList[i][reqarray[j]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot notation won't work with your code because you have strings in reqarray. Strings can be used to access members of an object using the bracket notation.

Eg:

```
var obj ={
name: 'x''
age: 22
};
```

Now you cannot use obj.'name' to access the name property of obj but can use obj['name'] to do so.

Therefore just change categoryList[i].reqarray[j] to 
categoryList[i][reqarray[j]] and you should be good to go..

So your code should be:

```
var categoryList = [ {"categoryName":"abcd","productName":"chicken biriyani","price":100,"quantity":"medium"}, {"categoryName":"biriyani","productName":"mutton biriyani","price":130,"quantity":"medium"} ];
for(var i in categoryList){
    var reqarray =['categoryName','productName','price','quantity'];
    for(var j in reqarray){
        if(categoryList[i][reqarray[j]]=='null' || categoryList[i][reqarray[j]] == " "){
            console.log("data is null");
        }
        else if(categoryList[i][reqarray[j]] == undefined){
            console.log("required parameters");
        }
        else{
            console.log("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I can use `obj.name` to access the object value although.

Comment: @arnabkaycee is it obj.name will work but obj.'name' won't

Answer (score 2):

One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map, dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names of the object's properties.

There are two ways to access properties: dot notation and bracket notation.

**Dot notation:**

```
get = object.property;
object.property = set;
```

Method call using dot notation:

```
document.createElement('pre');
```

**Bracket notation**

```
get = object[property_name];
object[property_name] = set;
```

Method call using bracket notation:

```
document['createElement']('pre');
```

In this case the literal `'createElement'` is known and you can directly access the property using the dot operator. In cases where `createElement` is a result of evaluation of an expression then you need to use the bracket notation, thereby instructing the JS compiler to evaluate what is inside the brackets first and then access the value at *evaluated* property of the object.

```
var categoryList = [ {"categoryName":"abcd","productName":"chicken biriyani","price":100,"quantity":"medium"}, {"categoryName":"biriyani","productName":"mutton biriyani","price":130,"quantity":"medium"} ];
for(var i in categoryList){

        var reqarray =['categoryName','productName','price','quantity'];
        for(var j in reqarray){
            if(categoryList[i][reqarray[j]]=='null' || categoryList[i][reqarray[j]] == " "){
                console.log("data is null");
            }
            else if(categoryList[i][reqarray[j]] == undefined){
                console.log("required parameters");
            }
            else{
                console.log("ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `arr` you meant `reqarray`, you just have to replace `categoryList[i].reqarray[j]` by `categoryList[i][reqarray[j]]`.

Also as a side note, you should not use `for..in` over arrays. Its meant for looping over objects. If you have arrays, use `for` or `array` functions.

**Sample**

```js
var categoryList = [{
  "categoryName": "abcd",
  "productName": "chicken biriyani",
  "price": 100,
  "quantity": "medium"
}, {
  "categoryName": "biriyani",
  "productName": "mutton biriyani",
  "price": 130,
  "quantity": "medium"
}];

var reqarray = ['categoryName', 'productName', 'price', 'quantity'];

categoryList.forEach(function(c) {
  reqarray.forEach(function(k) {
    if (c[k] == 'null' || c[k] == " ") {
      console.log("data is null");
    } else if (c[k] == undefined) {
      console.log("required parameters");
    } else {
      console.log("ok");
    }
  })
})
```